# Persistant Chat Window? Like Facebook or OkCupid

Tags: ajax, facebook, html

I saw this question asked here 18 months ago, but without (a correct) answer: [Window like facebook chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203805/window-like-facebook-chat)

Both Facebook and OkCupid have messaging windows which stay open even when you click to another page on their website.  Literally the IM window (and friend list, on Facebook) don't so much as flash or "blink" as if they were reloading quickly.  If you refresh the website (F5 or such) then the messages will disappear, at least for a moment.

The only thing I can think of is that the entire website never actually changes addresses, but just pushes the new URLs to your browser so it looks like the URL changed, but you never really left the same file.

How are they offering this persistent chat?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is they are using something similar to qjuery-pjax: 
https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

From their docs:

> pjax works by grabbing html from your server via ajax and replacing the content of a container on your page with the ajax'd html. It then updates the browser's current url using pushState without reloading your page's layout or any resources (js, css), giving the appearance of a fast, full page load. But really it's just ajax and pushState.

This means clicking a link on the page will load only part for page and leave the chat windows untouched (no flicker).  If you hit F5, the browser is initiating the refresh which will not use ajax/pushState. This causes the chat windows to flicker.